# Adaptive Card Title alignment problem in New Teams Application

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We are sending adaptive card from the application. Sometime for some user we noticed that adaptive card sent has broken header.

It actually showing icon, title and menu in stack instead of one line.

Below is adaptive card which we are using.

```
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"msTeams": {
  "width": "full"
},
"metadata": {
  "webUrl": "${applicationURL}"
},
"body": [
 {
  "type": "ColumnSet",
  "columns": [
    {
      "type": "Column",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "size": "Medium",
          "weight": "Bolder",
          "text": "[${cardTitle}](${applicationURL})"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "size": "Medium",
          "weight": "Bolder",
          "text": "${answerCount} ${answers} & ${voteCount} ${votes}"
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "weight": "default",
          "text": "${description}",
          "wrap": true
        },
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "weight": "default",
          "text": "${source}",
          "wrap": true
        }
      ],
      "width": "stretch"
    }
  ]
}
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.4"
}
```

This given below like output. Kindly suggest what's wrong here.

[image: Output image]

Update: 13 Feb

I have noticed issue in the Old teams as well. Here when collaborative StageView is open loop based adaptive card is broken which was showing perfectly in the normal chat. Now this one you can reproduce as its happening every time for me. Attaching image for your refs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We checked the JSON you shared and the card is rendered as shown in this screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIGOF.png. Could you please let us know how you are rendering the icon, title and menu? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOYcO.png

Comment: I might have answer for you, but same as with the other comment, please post your "action buttons" row so I can give you a better answer.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT this is card which will be unfurl when user search from from the application. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCBfE.png. This application name and icon pulled from the application.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I don't have any action buttons for this adaptive card.

Comment: ahh ok, I see now - I thought you -wanted- those buttons at the top. Try remove the "metadata" tag and see if it helps

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow metadata is needed to render loop based adaptive card. Do you think this is not picked up correctly by microsoft and they rendering card incorrectly.

Comment: I haven't worked with loop, but I've not seen Teams do this before and it's the only thing that looks unusual on the card. Are you able to test with it out?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow this is very intermittent issue. Above card is working perfectly with many users. Only some user are seeing this problem.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT can any one from your dev team have a look into above issue?

Comment: oh ok, got it. Does it maybe depend then on which version of Teams they are using (old vs new) maybe?

Comment: We checked this at our end in both Teams classic and new Teams 2.1. We are not able to repro this issue-https://i.stack.imgur.com/naFPJ.png. We reached out to engineering team. We will get back to you with an update.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I have updated issue and now I am able to reproduce issue. Can you check updated question.

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue. We will raise a bug for the same. We will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share bug id for the refs. also any ETA for the same since this is production issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, bug id is internal to Microsoft and cannot be shared. We are following up with engineering team for update. We will keep you posted.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, I understand that we won't have access to the progress of these bugs. We require this information solely for internal tracking purposes. Additionally, kindly update us if there have been any advancements on this matter or you receive any ETA for this issue.